# Undefined function for computed property ember-addons

Tags: ember-addon

Hi I just saw a tutorial on creating ember-addon using ember-cli.
replicating it
versions
Ember Inspector
1.7.3
Ember
1.11.1
Ember Data
1.0.0-beta.16.1
jQuery
1.11.3
EmberComputedFilter
0.0.0.547aa481

command
ember addon ember-computed-filter

//tests/dummy/app/controllers/application.js

```
import Em from 'ember';
export default Em.Controller.extend({
    name: 'Myname',
    trimmedName: function() {
        return this.get('name').trim();
    }.property('name')
});
```

Issue is definitely with computed property.
I am not sure of my controller is placed in right folder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this one https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/3645

from the guides. http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

```
// This won't work:
fullNameDidChange: function() {
  console.log("Full name changed");
}.observes('fullName')


// Instead, do this:
fullNameDidChange: Ember.observer('fullName', function() {
  console.log("Full name changed");
})
```